# Can not use the split() method

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I am trying to split a string which is an array element but the compiler say : type mismatch, can not convert from String[] to String. I don't understand because if we have an array of string the elements of this arrays must be of type String not String[]

This is the code:

```
while((s=buffereader.readLine())!=null)
{
    words=s.split(" "); 
    for (String word : words) 
    {
        s=words[0];
        s=s.split("T");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `words.equals(input)` to do exactly? **Which** word would be equal?

Comment: `words` is an array. Why would it be equals to a string?

Comment: Are you missing another loop after `words = s.split(" ")` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler is erroring on `s=s.split("T");` where `s` is a string, and not an array.

Simlarly, `words.equals(input)` doesn't do what you expect because an array will never equal a String. You would need to scan the array to see if any element was equal. If you use a modern IDE rather than compile in the CLI, then you may catch this error quicker.

Assuming you want to check if `input` is contained within each line, then split the first column on the letter `T`, this is what you want.

```
String s;
List<String> words;
while((s=buffereader.readLine()) != null) {
    words = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+"));  // Split by one _or more_ spaces
    if (words.contains(input)) {
        s = words.get(0);
        words = Arrays.asList(s.split("T"));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue. this is what i tried to do

```
public static void timeStamp() throws IOException {
        File log= new File(parametrization.link[15]);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(log);
        BufferedReader buffereader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String s;
        String[] s1;
        String[] words;
        String input="gracefully";
        while((s=buffereader.readLine())!=null)
         {
            words=s.split(" "); 
            for (String word : words) 
            {
            if (word.equals(input));
            {
                s=words[0];
                s1=s.split("T");

            }

            }
         }
```